# Difference between the expressions "at night" and "on the night"

Tags: difference

Tell me please what is the difference between the following sentences.

> 1 "Mike is going to sing **at night**."
>   2 "Mike is going to sing **on the night**."

Actually I thought that the preposition "at" have to be used before the word "night", but I have recently come across " on the night", so I am confused.

Comment: Could you give any examples of "on the night" you have found? As a native speaker, it's not a common phrase and I imagine would tend to be found in literature more than speech. EDIT: Or is "on the night" in the context of "he is going to sing *on the night* of the 20th January?"

Comment: @bilkokuya I interpreted the question as such as well in my answer. Unless the OP is studying archaic phrasing, I wouldn't expect them to see that wording.

Comment: on the night on its own does not exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second sentence, 'Mike is going to sing on the night,' can't be used on its own, but it's still correct.

In English, we usually use 'on the night' to describe a specific night. Of the various examples I could use, there are a few basic forms:

### Implicit Specification

Mike is actually a target for an assassination attempt by a terror organization. In all their correspondences between each other, they refer to 'the night,' though it's never stated that 'the night' is when they execute their plan (and Mike.)

In this case, sentences that refer to 'the night' are implicitly assumed to mean *that* night.

For example:

> Remember that Mike will be singing on the night. We need to take him out on stage.

### Inferred Specification

If, in a previous sentence, 'the night' is identified, then the value is used by inference. @Billy Kerr provided an excellent example of this in the comments:

> The concert will be held on Friday evening. It's going to be wonderful. Mike will sing on the night.

In this case, 'the night' refers to Friday evening.

### Extended Literal Specification

Maybe the sentence you provided wasn't complete. If I were to complete it, I'd expand it to something like:

> Mike is going to sing on the night of the 25th

This explicitly describes *which* night Mike will sing on within the scope of the sentence.

This usage could be better viewed as an   extension of 'on the (date)'. One would logically say

> Mike is going to sing on the 25th

which describes when Mike will sing. If we prepend 'the night of' to 'the 25th', then we talk more specifically about when Mike will sing.

### Noun Form

If 'On the Night' is the title of a song, then Mike would be singing that song.

---

### In conclusion

You can't use that grammar without the understanding that 'the night' refers to something specific.

Comment: Well said. Exactly.

Comment: No! The second sentence is ***not*** "grammatically incorrect"! It's a perfectly natural construction in contexts where ***the night*** is a specific known upcoming night. Consider the stereotypical theatre director saying: *It'll be alright **on the night*** (there will be a specific night when his play will be performed live, and that's what he's referring to). In OP's example the speaker might mean that although some other "stand-in" sang in the rehearsals, Mike will be the one singing on "Opening Night".

Comment: Oh, oops. I forgot about context dependent wording. Thanks for reminding me! I'll update my answer to include that.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't think it's fair to say ***on the night*** is "grammatically weird" either! It really is ***perfectly natural phrasing*** for contexts like my example (***or*** indeed, OP's example, ***if*** the speaker is referring to a specific night that the audience already know is ***the*** contextually-relevant night).

Comment: (As you yourself point out, the preposition ***on*** is natural when referring to a specific point in time such as ***on the 25th*** or ***on [the / Tuesday] night***).

Comment: But it is odd, though! Stand-in nouns aren't used all that often in natural speech, except for obfuscation of information. While I agree that it's correct in terms of raw grammar, it's not all that common. Should I use 'Unusual' instead of 'weird?'

Comment: I don't think it's odd or unusual. "On the night" could be used in certain contexts.  You could say something like "The concert will held on Friday evening. It's going to be wonderful. Mike is going to sing on the night". Here "the night" refers to "Friday night" - the night previously spoken about. It's true on it's own "on the night" seems wrong, but in context it's quite natural as @FumbleFingers has said.  You couldn't use "at night" in this context. That would be weird.

Comment: No, your example is redundant. You could simply say 'Mike is going to sing' and 'on Friday' would be inferred.

Comment: Due to repeated argument, I'm just gonna add a section explaining all this and stop calling the sentence weird.

Comment: Now with formatting! And quotes! And secret murder plots!

Comment: I can't say if I've ever heard "on the night" used on its own in any context.  Even in situations such as your first two examples it's always been followed by 'of'.  Ex.  "Will Mike be singing before or after the festival?" "He'll be singing on the night of."  Though now that I've said it, I think I've usually heard it without the 'on'.  Maybe it's a regionalism.

Comment: Nah, I'm just trying to cover my bases. If you read the comment thread above, there's a lively debate on whether that form is allowed.

Comment: @Jakob: You seem to be retreating from your erroneous initial position by degrees. First you said it's ***grammatically incorrect***, which you scaled back to ***grammatically weird, though not technically incorrect*** before settling on ***can't be used on its own***. I can't really see the point of that last version though - you probably wouldn't say the same about ***He** will sing tonight*, although obviously that couldn't be validly uttered unless ***his** identity* was contextually known (just as *on **the** night* must reference a single contextually-known night...

Comment: ...I think the bottom line is you still don't like the construction for reasons of your own, but I assure you it's ***perfectly natural English***.

Answer (score 1):

**at night** refers to the time of day.

> Some animals leave their burrows at night.

It is a general term.

**the night** can be used in a similar way, to refer to the time of day in general terms.

> She said she was a nocturnal animal, and that she loved the night.

But when we put the preposition **on** in front of the phrase, it can acquire a variety of meanings, as Jakob has ably set forth in his answer.

To those meanings we can add the meaning of "about" for **on**:

> We are going to hear a talk by a leading environmental critic of light-pollution. His talk is entitled *On The Night*.